# Getting OCRmyPDF to work with PDFMiner

Tags: homebrew, pdf, python

I'm trying to get [OCRmyPDF](https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF) to work on my Mac. I installed it successfully by running:

`brew install ocrmypdf`

But when I tried using it by running:

`ocrmypdf --redo-ocr input.pdf output.pdf`

I get this error:

> ERROR - (pdfminer is required for this feature. Your distribution may not have installed it.)

I tried installing PDFMiner by running `pip install pdfminer` and `pip install pdfminer.six`, but neither of those have done anything to make the error go away.

I don't really use Python/pip all that often, so I'm not sure what else to do.

How do I resolve this error and get OCRmyPDF working?

Comment: See if this works for you: https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF/issues/350#issuecomment-465745207